# Tradingview test the strategy with the given start date

Tags: pine-script

I want to test a strategy. However, no matter how I drag the chart, the start date of the test cannot earlier than 2020 Sep 01. I want to test it use earlier data. Is there a way to select the date range for Strategy Tester?

My scripts:

```
//@version=3
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

plotshape(longCondition, color = blue)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

plotshape(shortCondition, color = red)
```

I am using 15 minutes chart with ES as the trading target.
[image]

Is there a statement that can let the Backtesting be done with more data?

Thanks

Comment: There is a limitation of the available candle data. 5k, 10k and 20k bars for free, pro and premium members. You can enter a replay mode and scroll to the first bar and your data will be doubled, but there is no way to go earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the condition in script

```
//@version=4
date = input(title="Date", type=input.time, defval=timestamp("2020-09-01T00:00+03:00"))    
if (time_close >= date)
```